# Loading icon on IndicatingAjaxButton and IndicatingAjaxLink not showing

Tags: wicket

I am having issues with the loading icon on the IndicatingAjaxButton and
IndicatingAjaxLink. Previously I was on Wicket 9.0.0-M4 and the icons were working
fine. But after upgrading to Wicket 9.0.0-M5 (or later versions), I'm not
able to see the loading icon any longer.

I checked and found that the AjaxIndicatorAppender now has the
hidden attribute instead of the style=display:none. However, when I click
the IndicatingAjaxButton, it will still append the style=display:inline as
before (with the hidden attribute still present).

I've not done any changes to the dependency, only upgrade the Wicket versions. Is there anything that I would need for the upgrade for the button to work?

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Please create a mini demo application demonstrating the issue with Wicket 9.7.0 and share it at Github or similar, and we can take a look!

Comment: After checking my codes and comparing them to examples from Wicket 9x, found the cause of the issue was from wicket bootstrap.css
[hidden] {
    display: none !important;
}